# ow do I use the materialkit switch on and off in a case statement or in a if-else statement for a function?

Tags: cosmicmind

How do I use the materialkit switch on and off in a case statement or in a if-else statement for a function? It seems that the UIcontrol and Material Kit has two different syntax.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For Material, it is like this.

```
let materialSwitch = MaterialSwitch()

if .On == materialSwitch.switchState {
    // Do something
} else {
   // Do something else....
}
```